# Vb.net Equivalent exception for Vb6 Error code

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Hi i am using the vb6 code Logic in my application where i need to manage the error handling. In vb6 ADODB.Errors are used for capturing the exception.

I want to know the exception equivalent in vb.net for the Vb6 ADODB.Error codes

1. 2147217885 (0x80040e23) A given HROW referred to a hard- or soft-deleted row.
2. 2147217887 0x80040e21 Errors occurred

Can anyone please help to know the equivalent exception for the above two error codes

Comment: You shouldn't use ADODB in .NET. If you use SqlCommand, then the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) [explain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) which exceptions are throwned.

Comment: I don't know the equivalent for the two exceptions in vb.net(sqlexceptions) for the mentioned vb6 exceptions. Kindly help

Comment: Thus seems a bit Cargo Cult - you should forget about the VB6 specifics and look at the exceptions thrown by SQLCommand, handling them as appropriate.

Comment: I can understand that sqlcommand generates exception specific to .net but these two are the common exceptions codes which can arise when we delete the records in the Parent - child relational table. so if i know the equivalent for these two errors i.e what is exception. so i can use the exception and manipulate the catch statement in my code

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [This,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8877bdk6.aspx)
in particular the section on "Unhandled Errors in Event Handlers".  It explains how to use the ADODB Errors collection in a try/catch block.

I don't think you're going to find a way to trap ADODB errors by using equivalent errors thrown in the .Net environment.  There aren't one-to-one equivalencies between COM errors and .Net exceptions in general.  What happens in this case with ADODB Error objects is that .Net uses interop marshaling to throw the error object into the catch block, wrapping it with the Exception object.  You can evaluate the error there.  However, the doc doesn't explain how you can iterate the Errors collection to see both of your errors.  Perhaps you can post how that's done here once you've figured it out.